# What is the name of the technique used when substituting a word?

Tags: literary-techniques

I just came out of an exam where an author used byte instead of bite in a line. The line was, "creating fake profiles, but at least she gets a byte of midnight love". It's driving me absolutely crazy because I just can't remember the name of the technique, substituting a word with another that sounds like it because it further exhibits that the character is online or whatever. Please help, I'm going insane.

Comment: It sounds like it was employing the use of a homonym in a pun.

Comment: I suspect squidlydeux is correct and it might help it you could post a passage, or a link to one…